# Putting a Twitter Bootstrap progress bar inside a navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to write a small music player with jPlayer and Twitter Bootstrap. For the controls I'm using a navbar component with icons as buttons, to display the position in the current song I want to use a progress bar, but when I place it inside the navbar it gets stuck on the top.

So far I'm working with this code: http://jsfiddle.net/m5Lkk/1/

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-play"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-stop"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="nav navbar-text progress" style="width: 300px;">
                <div class="bar" style="width: 30%;"></div>
            </div>
            <p class="nav navbar-text pull-right">13:37</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how I get the progress bar verically centered inside the navbar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know it's dirty, but what about this:

http://jsfiddle.net/m5Lkk/9/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-play"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-stop"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="nav navbar-text progress" style="width: 300px; margin-top:10px">
                <div class="bar" style="width: 30%;"></div>
            </div>
            <p class="nav navbar-text pull-right">13:37</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've basically added a margin so it pushes it down a little.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 4, Sandeep Bansal's solution doesn't seem to work anymore (progress bar, but no filling

I got it working like this: add a fixed width to the surrounding div that has the `progress` class in it. Put that div outside the `<ul>` tags.

For example:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank">Link</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="progress" style="width: 50em"> <!-- 50em = half the screen width -->
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```